# Переход на pytest 5, как отказаться от pytest.config и не погрязнуть в request

Tags: pytest

У меня есть класс environment, в котором определяется стенд(тестовое, пред-боевое, боевое окружение) и выбираются нужные настройки. 
Выглядит это вот так:

```py
    @classmethod
    def new_stand(cls, stand: str) -> 'Environment':
        return cls(stand=stand)

    @property
    def environment_name(self) -> str:
        stand = (
            pytest.config.getoption('--stand', default='')
            if hasattr(pytest, 'config')
            else self.stand
        )

        return stand.lower()
```

В pytest 5.0.0 и выше, отказались от `pytest.config`, и предлагают использовать `request.config`, и да, там есть нужное значение, но значит придется прокинуть этот request везде, а это достаточно много мест.

Возможно ли, сделать как-то иначе, не умирая в добавлении `requests` везде?

Answer (score 0):

В качестве "быстрого и грязного" костыля можно присвоить `config` обратно в модуль. Добавь в `conftest.py`:

```
@pytest.fixture(autouse=True)
def inject_config(request):
    pytest.config = request.config
```

В дальнейшем можно сделать инъекцию конфига в тестовые классы. Для одного класса:

```
class TestCls:
    @pytest.fixture(autouse=True)
    def inject_config(self, request):
        self.config = request.config

    @property
    def environment_name(self) -> str:
        return self.config.getoption('--stand', default='')
```

Для всех классов:

```
@pytest.fixture(autouse=True, scope='class')
def inject_config(request):
    request.cls.config = request.config


class TestCls:
    @property
    def environment_name(self) -> str:
        return self.config.getoption('--stand', default='')
```

`pytest.config` на `self.config` все равно придется поменять везде, но можно сделать за один проход, к примеру, с помощью `sed`:

```
$ find tests/ -type f -exec sed -i 's/pytest.config/self.config/g' {} +
```